# how to add mecab library in aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda

I'm trying to add mecab library to aws lambda layer but it didn't work.

What I want is to tokenize Japanese and Korean languages. Tokenizing is enough.

Here's what I have done. (I referred to this site: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-python-packages-for-aws-lambda-layer-74e193c76a91 for installing python packages for aws lambda layers)

1. AWS EC2 docker installation.
2. Build docker file

```
sudo vi Dockerfile

-----------------vi editor------------------
FROM amazonlinux:2.0.20191016.0
RUN yum install -y python37 && \
    yum install -y python3-pip && \
    yum install -y zip && \
    yum clean all
RUN python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3.7 -m pip install virtualenv
-----------------vi editor------------------


docker build -t lambdalayer .
```

2. Run

```
docker run -it --name lambdalayer lambdalayer:latest bash
```

3. Install python packages

```
python3.7 -m venv mypackages

source mypackages/bin/activate

pip install mecab-python3 -t ./python
pip install unidic-lite -t ./python
pip install --no-binary :all: mecab-python3 -t ./python
pip install -v python-mecab-ko -t ./python

deactivate
```

4. zip file

```
zip -r python.zip ./python/

docker cp lambdalayer:python.zip /home/ubuntu/
```

5. AWS s3 upload

```
cd /home/ubuntu

aws s3 cp python.zip s3://bukketyounghee
```

6. Make a lmabda layer

```
aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name layer-search --compatible-runtimes "python3.7" --content S3Bucket=bukketyounghee,S3Key=python.zip
```

I don't know what I should do next. It doesn't have to be mecab library but I want to use aws lambda because I want a serverless application. Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Glad it worked. If my answer was helpful, it's acceptance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a  [lambda layer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) using **docker** as described in the [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/).

Thus you can add `mecab` to your function as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
mecab-python3
unidic-lite
```

3. Run the following docker command:

The command will create layer for python3.8:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Archive the layer as zip:

```
zip -9 -r mylayer.zip python
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mylayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtime` to `python3.8`.
6. Add the the layer created in step 5 to your function.
7. I tested the layer using your code:

```
import json

import MeCab

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        
    wakati = MeCab.Tagger("-Owakati")

    a = wakati.parse("pythonが大好きです").split()
    return  {
        'statusCode': 200,  
        'body': json.dumps(a)
        }
```

It  works **correctly**:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "[\"python\", \"\\u304c\", \"\\u5927\\u597d\\u304d\", \"\\u3067\\u3059\"]"
}
```

Comment: Thank you su much! You saved me! It worked out