# How to make a mecab-ko as AWS Lambda Layer?

Tags: mecab, korean-nlp

From the answer to [how to add mecab library in aws lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67545724/how-to-add-mecab-library-in-aws-lambda), I could make a lambda layer of mecab library.
However, mecab-ko does not seem to be working in the same way.
Could anyone please guide me?